# get_post_meta() not work for the first post inside the loop

Tags: post-meta

I need to add a different custom class to each div inside my wordpress loop. I've read about `post_class()` function and filter, but I'm not sure if it's a good approach to do this. For now I have this code, and I'm using the `get_post_meta()` to get the custom field I set with the class I want to display, but it will work only for the second post displayed. Is there a fix or I need to use the `post_class()` instead?

```
<?php $scrollable = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'home-slider', 'posts_per_page' => 3] ); ?>
<?php if( $scrollable->have_posts() ): while( $scrollable->have_posts() ): $scrollable->the_post(); ?>
<?php $class = get_post_meta($post->ID,'class',true); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 img-<?php echo $class; ?>"> <!-- For each div of the loop I need to assign the img-top ecc... custom class -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 img-text">
            <h1 class="">Hello</h1>
            <p class="lead">Nice to meet you.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="img-fluid bg-img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
      </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Try to use get_the_ID() instead of $post->ID in the get_post_meta function within a loop.

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar already tried, the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

In that case try to create custom sql query like this.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=your post id AND meta_key='class';    
$results = $wpdb->get_row($query) ;  echo $results->meta_value;
```

Comment: I can try, but I want to understand why the field is saved correctly and not displaayed.